# I want to set a Image on UINavigationBar without using nib please help me?

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0

please help me to set the image on UINavigationBar without using nib.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to override the `- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect` method with something like this:

```
UIImage *image  = [UIImage imageNamed: @"filename.png"];
[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
```

Basically this load an image from a file and then draws it with the exact size of the UINavigationBar.

Comment: there I need to write a categories for UINavigationBar??